# CasperJS fill form when fields have no name

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm new to CasperJS and I'm trying to fill up a form. I have followed the tutorials, but my problem is that the form I'm trying to fill in has no form element name.

```
<form class="login-form" action="#" method="post">

    <input type="text" tabindex="1" class="login-user input-block-level" placeholder="Username" />

    <input type="text" tabindex="1" class="login-password input-block-level" placeholder="Password" />
```

How can I target these fields?

Comment: cant you target with classname ? with `.login-form >.login-user` something like that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`casper.fillSelectors()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#fillselectors) fill form fields by any CSS selector that you can think of. Those seem fine:

```
casper.then(function(){
    this.fillSelectors('form.login-form', {
        'input.login-user': 'my username',
        'input.login-password': 'my password'
    }, true);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. i will try this and let u know the result.

Comment: Nothing happened, it did not fill up the form.

Comment: Which PhantomJS version do you use? Please register to the `resource.error`, `page.error`, `remote.message` and `casper.page.onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-2_caspererrors-js)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: Hello im using PhantomJS: 2015-01-23: Version 2.0.0 and latest casperjs.. both download just last week, i already implemented the example above and it show no errors and the above function is not called the casper.fillselectors()

Comment: How do you check whether it worked? Do you take a screenshot? How do you do this? The screenshot must be taken in a different step to `casper.then(function(){this.fillSelector(...);}); casper.then(function(){this.capture(filename);});`